# What information does the connectome actually contain?

Tags: neuroscience, memory, brain

I am not a brain scientist but the following question seems reasonable to me.

Prof. Sebastian Seung has given a TED talk named "I Am My Connectome". If I understand correctly, connectome is basically the graph whose vertices are neurons and whose edges are synapses (strictly speaking, there are many different kinds of neurons so the vertices of the graph should be colored, but let us forget it for now).

The title then appears to be a (probably intentional) oversimplification, since even though we do not understand how exactly memories are stored in the brain (and there are many different kinds of memories), things I will roughy call "electrical and chemical variables" play some role in it (so simply remembering whether there is a link or not between two neurons is not going to fly). I understand that studying these "electrical and chemical variables" is like over a half of the brain science but the exact definition is not particularly important for this question. If my understanding is correct, then one should not get overly excited about the present achievements of the Brain Preservation Foundation (the most promising one is, I think, preserving the connectome of a mammal for some time after its death using a chemical solution/freezing), since they have not shown that they can preserve any of the "electrical and chemical variables".

The question is: what information can you actually extract out of a connectome, assuming you do not know anything else about the brain? Like something about a person's health, personality, anything? The chance of them having schizophrenia? Their most likely age?

Answer (score 1):

### Well, regarding this short definition of a connectome from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectome):

> A connectome (/kəˈnɛktoʊm/) is a comprehensive map of neural
> connections in the brain, and may be thought of as its "wiring
> diagram". More broadly, a connectome would include the mapping of **all
> neural connections** within an organism's nervous system.

Therefore **you could read out *all* information, assuming you have enough computational power.** (A perfect connectome would represent all information processes in the brain. Because processing information through connections is all the brain does, right? :D)

In the real world however, we need **'models' as simplifications** to deal with these phenomena. A connectome is nothing else than such a model.

### Influential Factors to consider

1. To **make predictions of real-world constructs, you need to assess real-world phenomena**. F.i. you need to have
   postulated some outcome-variables (for lets say Schizophrenia) that need to
   be quantified in the real-world *(external validity)* to be related to
   inner-brain processes. These real-world concepts of psychological
   processes, speaking of the behavioral, emotional and cognitive
   aspects (which can be measured), are inherently fuzzy, which raises
   the question, to which certainty we will be able to predict
   psycho-physiological correlates.
2. Not to forget, memories are mainly coded as '**processes over-time**',
   something like chains of activation (other than distinct anatomy and
   brain-areas who would define thoughts). Also noisyness and
   randomness is always a variable you need to consider. (I think the
   Hippocampus functioning of neurons induces randomness by design, but
   I have no source right now.)
3. Also to mention:
   The **individuality of brains** leads to decreased prediction of the model or a general model that would hold for every individual
4. The **plasticity** of the brain states states the ability to change and
   evolve over time.  (Concepts like Imprinting and so on). A static
   model might also not be sufficient to represent these (also highly
   individualized) processes.
5. **Situational- or environmental dependency** also influences your
   current state of mind. (It is not possible to 'control' all
   environmental factors, unless you had infinite computational power.)
6. Also the brain and **toughts are highly self-/auto-activating, recurring and in parallel**.
   Millions of neurons firing at the same time and oscillating in
   rhythms. Thoughts that become conscious might only be the tip of the
   iceberg in a sea of thoughts that are below a certain threshold.

### My proposal to your question: "What exactly can you get from a connectome?"

*In principle everything is possible, but practically we might never truely decode everything from a philosopical and mathematical point-of-view (we needed to create a perfect connectome, which would be a perfect simulation of the entire brain). We might however be able to find **very accurate brain-markers** that help in **predicting real-world concepts** that seem relevant for humans* :)

### Resources

Because it is great: [Video of synchronizing fireflies](https://youtu.be/sROKYelaWbo)

Buszaki: [Rhythms of the Brain](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/rhythms-of-the-brain-9780199828234?cc=de&lang=en&) is a nice read on some how information is created in the brain and different processes

Comment: I do not understand your answer. What is "wiring diagram" supposed to mean? In each synapse, you have thousands and thousands of dynamical variables (concentration of this neutrotransmitter, of that neurotransmitter). Are they considered a part of the connectome or not? If not, then how can we extract all the information (you talk about computational power, so you probably have an algorithm)? If yes, then does the definition of the connectome simply mean "the entire brain"?

Comment: Each synapse and each neuron surely plays a part of the communication processes. But I guess more implicitely in the case of a Connectome. like any communication/information process in the world is using atoms, though you would usually not describe these processes on an atom level. (Maybe (Quantum) Information Theory does). A Connectome would probably focus on whole brain communication processes.

Comment: But then it is unclear how is connectome a useful definition. If the definition was something like "get only these precise pieces on information from the brain, then the rest can be computed from them", it could have been useful. But apparently, the definition is just "all the information in the brain is considered a part of the connectome too". Then connectome is just a fancy word for brain. And then it is not surprising that you can read out all information from the connectome.

Comment: and I believe there has been some work on determining whether a person has schizophrenia (a fuzzy notion, as described in your answer) by eye movement (something fairly objective). So while your general point is reasonable, there are apparently some ways to extract something concrete out this fuzzy notion. https://www.nhs.uk/news/mental-health/100-accurate-eye-test-for-schizophrenia-claim/

Comment: It is the job of scientists to extract information out of a fuzzy world. Didn't say otherwise. 
And because everything is interconnected, you cannot ultimately explain the brain by either a large scale communcation model (connectome as 'one' out of many models for large-scale dynamics), or a synapse level or a chemical level, and so on, all alone. The Connectome just focusses on the larger scale communication.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I can not understand this sentence: "you could read out all information, assuming you have enough computational power". Please tell me precisely what information is considered a part of the connectome? What is a comprehensive map of neural connections? And then to explain the sentence itself, exactly what manipulations with that information are you going to do to extract the rest? Or is there actually no definition of connectome, and it just represents some notion we do not completely understand?

Comment: A Connectome (not sure about where the word is originating, it might not be a widely used term in neuroscience) is simply a mapping of connections in the brain on a larger scale. What region communicates with what region. If you could measure all the details, every synapse as well, the model could be way more complex, but the technologies have its limits. As I said, there are technologies for measuring behavior of single neurons as well, and so on, there is a lot more neurophysiological technologies. Currently I think the Connectome is nearly solely based on fMRI.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now. So connectome is kind of a template for a definition, but precisely what information enters it is in the eyes of the beholder (and if the eye's resolving power is high enough, we can see everything, that's what you meant from my understanding).

Comment: Well kind of, the eye is a classic example - a signal travelling from the eye to some nuclei to the back of your head. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_system (Neuroanatomy topic is essentially the same as a connectome, which roots from the fMRI research area)  If you could anatomically rebuild exactly every neuron, then this would be the perfect model, but this is not possible and 'would need infinite processing power'

Comment: the eye was meant as an analogy, but thanks for the information.

Comment: sure^^ you're welcome